# Absolute value equation with parameter p

Tags: absolute-value, parameter-estimation

I know how to calculate absolute functions without parameter:

⋅ | + 6| = 36

The question is how parameter p changes the number of solutions.

I tried to somehow calculate the discriminant for the positive and negative case but using GeoGebra I found out that if p is less than -2 than it has 3 solutions, however when it was -2 it had 2 solutions and finally when it was greater than -2 it had only one solution.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Also, clarifying the question would help.  Note that the usual idea is to break into cases, according to the sign of the relevant expression..

Comment: Solve it the same way you would do it if p had  a fixed value.